# Parse error on input ']' when running cabal build in my Plutus code

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cabal

I have a code that compiles and runs well in the Plutus playground, but when I try to run cabal build I get an error when calling mkTypedValidator:

```
offerValidator :: Scripts.TypedValidator Offer
offerValidator = Scripts.mkTypedValidator @Offer
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| validateOffer ||])
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| wrap ||]) where
        wrap = Scripts.wrapValidator @OfferData @OfferAction
```

[image: parse error on input ‘]’]

- using ghc version ghc-8.10.7
- cabal version 3.6.0

Any ideas what might be happening? Not very experienced with cabal/plutus yet.

Also already tried `cabal update` but looks like everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns               #-}
```

Looks like I was missing some imports that are not necessary in the playground, but are still necessary when building with cabal. Will leave this here since it may help someone else :)